# How to change the fontsize of the \part command

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, parts

I am using the `report` style and I would just like to change the fontsize of the `\part` command. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's another option, using the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) package (instead of `\large`, use the font size that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\partfont{\large}

\begin{document}

\part*{A test unnumbered part}
\part{A test numbered part}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can patch the relevant command by the »[etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)« package. The `\@part` macro is responsible for the formatting of the part prefix and the heading itself. It contains two commands that determine the font sizes. Hence you have to patch it two times.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}{\huge}{\normalsize}{}{}   % Choose your favorite size instead of \normalsize
\patchcmd{\@part}{\Huge}{\normalsize}{}{}   % Choose your favorite size instead of \normalsize
\patchcmd{\@spart}{\Huge}{\normalsize}{}{}  % Choose your favorite size instead of \normalsize
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \part{Foo}
\end{document}
```

Choose the font size that you need as remarked in the comments.

As remarked in the comments, I added a patch for the `\@spart` macro that is responsible for unnumbered part headings.

Comment: +1, but consider to add a patch for `\@spart` (unnumbered parts).

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks for the hint. I have supplemented my example correspondingly.